# Unet Unity islocal player error

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am testing out the Unet multiplayer functionality on a basic 2d game. At the moment it consists of a single box/racket moving up and down. In the  monobehaviour class the box moves up and down correctly, however when i include the islocalplayer in the networkbehaviour class the box does not move up and down. When I play the game the network information box says islocal no. How do i go about changing this. [image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class MoveRacket : NetworkBehaviour
{
  public float speed= 30;
  public string axis = "Vertical"; 

  void Update()
  {

    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
       return;
    }

    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw(axis);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, v) * speed;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it in the network manager game object > spawn information > check auto create player

Answer (score 0):

`isLocalPlayer` is in the `NetworkObject` file, try to open the `NetworkObject` script and find:

```
public bool IsLocalPlayer => NetworkManager.Singleton != null && IsPlayerObject && OwnerClientId == NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId;
```

if it is there you should change `isLocalPlayer` to `IsLocalPlayer`.